# Edit text expands vertically when more text entered in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a layout with many view and one of them is edit text with a back ground image. Everything is fine until there is only few lines but when there is more lines of text entered edit text starts expanding and also it pushes other view below which is not expected.

I have made the width to be wrapcontent. pls find the layout code below

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dsh" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:maxHeight="250dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

Comment: Give some fixed width of edit text instead of setting to fill_parent

Comment: Then you cannot use `wrap_content`. Either use fixed width or `match_parent`.

Comment: i am worried about vertical expansion @ShreyaShah

Comment: That's because of android:singleLine="false". Set it to true